# How to retrieve a 1:1-associated Entity Extension with the store-api (Shopware 6.5)

Tags: shopware6

I have defined and registered an entity extension `my_category` that extends the Category entity, using a 1:1 association like this

```php
...
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
                (new OneToOneAssociationField(
                        'myCategory',
                        'id',
                        'category_id',
                        MyCategoryDefinition::class
                ))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete())
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return CategoryDefinition::class;
    }
...
```

Adding and retrieving data to this extension using the entity repository works without a hitch. Now I want to add fields from this extension to the store-api. I have tried adding a body

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://mysite.tld/store-api/category' \
--header 'sw-access-key: xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{   
    "includes": {
        "category": [
            "name",
            "myCategory"
        ]
    }
}'
```

to no avail. Tracing the request in HttpKernel I can see the entity repository perfectly retrieves the extension with all its fields. However, the response of my request does not show the extension's data. It is just

```json
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "Topseller",
            "apiAlias": "category"
        }
    ],
...
```

What is the correct way and notation to retrieve data from a 1:1 association using the store-api?

(My version is Shopware 6.5.4.0. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [`ApiAware` flag](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/core-reference/dal-reference/flags-reference) to make the fields exposable for the Store-API.

```php
(new OneToOneAssociationField(
    'myCategory',
    'id',
    'category_id',
    MyCategoryDefinition::class
))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete(), new ApiAware())
```

Same for the fields of `MyCategoryDefinition` that should be exposed.

```php
(new StringField('keyword', 'keyword'))->addFlags(new ApiAware())
```

Comment: Thx, I had this flag on my fields, but just missed it on the association field!